# A good way to proof to my teacher that java streams can have worse performance than a simple for

Tags: java, optimization, java-stream

My teacher is convinced that it is convenient to use streams when looping over a list because operations can be parallelized.

I understand that this is true in some ways, but I think that we could always implement a faster code writing it by ourselves.

We are talking here of use cases where we want to optimize as much as we can.

Suppose that we start with the following code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        List<Something> ls = new ArrayList<Something>();
        ls.add(new Something(true));
        ls.add(new Something(false));

        System.out.println("Active things: " + getActive(ls).size());
    }

     public static List<Something> getActive(List<Something> listOfThings){
        return listOfThings != null? listOfThings.stream().filter(t -> t.isActive()).collect(Collectors.toList()): null;
     }

     public static class Something {
         public Something(boolean active) {
             this.active = active;
         }
         private boolean active;

         public boolean isActive() {
             return active;
         }

         public void justDoIt() {
             System.out.println("done");
         }
     }
}
```

Isn't true that, the method getActive() can be optimized avoiding the use of streams ?

I understand that it is easier to use streams, but because they have to be general purpose, they will never be faster than well written and optimized code.

For example, if the list is very big and we know that it would be convenient to parallelize the loop on three cores, couldn't we just execute in three different threads the loop with a standard iterator?

Comment: "How can I prove that I am right?" is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Is it really so generic my question? I think that I asked a specific question on optimization. If you like, please suggest a different title.

Comment: Completed code is always faster than uncompleted code. Sure, you can probably write a faster optimized specific solution for a specific problem. Or you can be happy with good-enough performance reusing prebuilt tools (that's what streams are: a tool) and finish the task in a fraction of the time. Often, the latter is better for a broad range of definitions of "better." Sometimes, the former is. It sounds to me like your teacher is simply avoiding premature optimization. Optimize when there's a problem, not before. (That way, you have time to solve the actual problems when the appear.)

Comment: It is almost **never** true that using a parallel `Stream` is faster than a simple `for` loop. Tasks need to take tens or even _hundreds_ of milliseconds before parallelising them makes things faster - anything less than than and the concurrency overheads outweigh the benefits from parallelism. Your teacher seems to have an **incredibly** naive understanding of how concurrency works, and is applying the "rule of new" when they should be looking at _evidence_.

Comment: P.S. your `getActive` method is awful. Either use a `Stream` and Java 8 constructs or use older declarative constructs; do not mix the two into weird and illegible hybrids.

Comment: Code requiring optimization requests belong on [codereview.se], not [so].

Comment: @BoristheSpider getActive() is only a short example. It means only that a method is called on the object. In the same time, I have seen that construct used many times. I do not see in what sense is awful.

Comment: "we could always implement a faster code writing it by ourselves" - depends what you mean by "faster". If you want it 10% "faster", it might make sense to use a `for`-loop. If you want it 10000% "faster", you invent something like `stream`-api, and then you generalize it to something like Apache Spark. It happens to be that `for`-loops don't scale nicely, while the general transformation operations like those provided by `stream`-API *do scale nicely*. See it as an exercise that prepares you for big-data processing frameworks, not as an exercise that makes you good in low-level optimization.

Comment: It sounds like both your teacher, and you, hold some simplistic assumptions about performance.  I would advise you both to focus instead on writing code that is clear and correct; the vast majority of the time, the clear and correct code is fast enough (or even faster.)  Reasoning about (or measuring) performance in complex, dynamically compiled systems is far more complicated than you give it credit for.